# Python Valid IPs from each line on a text file

Tags: python, validation, copy, ip

I have a text file which include many ips in this format

```
Host : x.x.x.x , DNS : resolved dns , Location : USA
Host : x.x.x.x , DNS : resolved dns , Location : USA
Host : x.x.x.x , DNS : resolved dns , Location : USA
```

I want to take the VALID ips after the phrase "Host : " which is the first word in the line and move it to file ipclear.txt , discarding any ip from the same line just the Valid ip after the phrase Host .

Comment: what did you do so far?

Comment: What's the main problem here? extracting ip, validate it or writing in a file?

Comment: @MohammedAldaouldi the answer I have will only return the Host. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('inputfile.txt','r')
clearip = open('clearip.txt','w')

for line in f:
    ip = line.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].strip()
    clearip.write(ip+'\n')

f.close() # you can omit in most cases as the destructor will call if
clearip.close()
```

This will open two files, one is the file you're reading from, the other is the file you're writing to. Then it will go through the input file line by line. For each line we split it at the `,`s, then the `:`s, assuming the file is in the same format that you posted, this will leave us with the IP address, which we then call `strip()` on to remove any trailing or leading whitespace. We then write this IP to the output file, and add the newline character. After this we close the text files.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `socket` package has a function that converts a valid IP of dotted octets to an integer. It's called `inet_aton`, which is short for 'internet address to number'.

The `try: [...] except:` attempts to convert the string between 'Host :' and ' , DNS : ' to an IP integer, and it if fails, it just quietly moves on to the next line. It's easier to leverage socket than write your own regex to parse out all the possible valid IP's.

```
import re
import socket

ipPattern = re.compile('Host : (.*) , DNS : .*')

outfile = open('ipclear.txt', 'w')

for line in open('iplog.txt').readlines():
    ipString = ipPattern.match(line).group(1)
    try:
        socket.inet_aton(ipString)
        outfile.write(ipString + '\n')
    except:
        pass

outfile.close()
```

Comment: this code will take the dns value also , I don't need it . I just want the Host value and to validate this value if its a correct ip or not then take it

Comment: The code writes out the list of valid IP addresses immediately to the right of 'Host :' from the input file. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: You can see example inputs and output here: https://gist.github.com/alexwoolford/ed24f5fb621ce16670cb

Comment: yes , but i want only the value in Host : x.x.x.x , if there is any other ip like DNS : 1.1.1.1 i don't want it to be included

Comment: also this code gave me the error "ipString = ipPattern.match(line).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'"